# Finite Difference Scheme for the KdV equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

In this now famous [paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.15.240) by Zabusky and Kruskal, the authors use a finite difference scheme to numerically integrate the Korteweg-de Vries equation:

$$u_t+uu_x+\delta^2u_{xxx}=0$$
 The formula they use looks something like (footnote 6):
$$u_{n}^{m+1}=u_{n}^{m-1}-\frac{h_t}{3h_x}\left(u_{n+1}^m+u_n^m+u_{n-1}^m\right)\left(u_{n+1}^{m}-u_{n-1}^m\right)-\frac{\delta^2h_t}{h_x^3}\left(u_{n+2}^m-u_{n-2}^m-2\left(u_{n+1}^m-u_{n-1}^m\right)\right)$$
where $h_t,h_x$ are the spacing in time and space, respectively. How did the authors arrive at this formula? I recognize the last term on the RHS as a typical discretization of the third derivative, and it seems like the time discretization is a centered-Euler method, but this doesn't work out to be the same for me.

Comment: It may be worth asking instead at scicomp.stackexchange; that's where the numerics specialists gather.

Comment: I did several hours ago, but I'm going to delete that post because it didn't get any attention.

Comment: Hours? You are asking on a weekend and you expect instantaneous response for what is a pretty technical and specialist question? I am aghast.  Given the typical traffic at scicomp I would wait at least a **week** before declaring that my question didn't get any attention.

Comment: This isn't that technical of a question, and I have asked questions on that site in the past and have waited weeks for an answer. I think, to be up in arms feeling aghast for taking this action is a bit melodramatic. I've been patient in the past with other questions and just decided to bring it here instead. Edit - I am not insinuating anything about scicomp, but it is evident they don't get as much foot traffic as here.

Comment: All the discretizations used here, apart from $u$ perhaps, are quite standard: symmetric time-derivatives for $u_x$ and $u_t$ and the $5$-point stencil for $u_{xxx}$. This becomes more clear by writing it as $$\color{brown}{\frac{u_{n}^{m+1}-u_{n}^{m-1}}{2h_t}}=-\left(\color{red}{\frac{u_{n+1}^m+u_n^m+u_{n-1}^m}{3}}\right)\left(\color{blue}{\frac{u_{n+1}^{m}-u_{n-1}^m}{2h_x}}\right)-\delta^2\left(\color{green}{\frac{u_{n+2}^m-2u_{n+1}^m+ 2u_{n-1}^m-u_{n-2}^m}{2h_x^3}}\right)$$ Note however that they use $\frac{u_{i-1}+u_i+u_{i+1}}{3}$ as an approximation for $u$ (instead of simply $u_i$).

Comment: I was wondering like crazy where the red business was coming from and didn't realize they were just taking a local spatial average of u. Thanks for clearing that up.